# Angular8:memory leaks in formGroup

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular8 application.Here i have created the sample project on [github](https://github.com/CP-Ram/AngularFromGroupMemoryLeakTestApp).

steps:

-open the Dev Tool performance tab ->Right side `customize and control DevTools`.

-click on `show console drawer`.

-click bottom left `performance monitor`.

-click on `JS heap size` in left pane.

-now click on application button `initForm` and `destroyForm` process **repeat 4-5** times.

i am setting myGroup as null ngOndestroy and Observable valuechanges destroying but still retaining memory size.

here is the memory retained size and heap screenshot after destroy form([image])

**Updated:**
[FormControlComponent.ts](https://github.com/CP-Ram/AngularFromGroupMemoryLeakTestApp/blob/master/src/app/hello.component.ts)

**component.ts**

```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { startWith, pairwise, distinctUntilChanged,takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngIf="initialze" [formGroup]="myForm" >
    <div formArrayName="lists" *ngFor="let a of myForm.get('lists').controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy  {


 isFormInitialized = false;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  AuditUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public unsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  groupName = "lists";
  property = "name";
  initialze = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let controlarray1 = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    this.myForm.addControl(this.groupName, controlarray1);
    let groupControl = this.formBuilder.control(null);

    const control = this.myForm.controls[this.groupName] as FormArray;
    this.myForm.setControl(this.groupName, control);
    var listControl = this.formBuilder.group({});
    var ctr = this.formBuilder.control(null);
    listControl.addControl("name", ctr);
    control.push(listControl);
    console.log(this.myForm);

    this.subsubscribeToFormControlValueChanges(listControl, ctr, "name");
    this.initialze = true;
  }

   ngOnDestroy(){
    this.myForm = null;
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
    this.AuditUnsubscribe.next()
    this.AuditUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  subsubscribeToFormControlValueChanges(
    group: FormGroup,
    fctrl: FormControl,
    propertyName
  ) {
    if (fctrl) {
      fctrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          startWith(null),
          pairwise(),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
          )
        .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
          // var configId = group.get("name");
          console.log(next);
        });
    }
  }


}
```

Please any help.

Thanks.

Comment: No code, no possibility to help.

Comment: Hey @philippMeissner,I already provided github link .i have updated again my question...please don't give down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you init form , you recreate a `hello` component where subscribe on form value changes. But do not unsubscribe from it. I think you need to use `takeUntil` operator in your subscribe method.

```
    subsubscribeToFormControlValueChanges(
          group: FormGroup,
          fctrl: FormControl,
          propertyName
      ) {
        if (fctrl) {
          fctrl.valueChanges
            .pipe(
              startWith(null),
              pairwise(),
              distinctUntilChanged(),
              takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
            )
            .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
              // var configId = group.get("name");
              console.log(next);
            });
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply.but it's not working..still taking memory after destroy.